# GO Channels ending abruptly?

Tags: go, channel

I'm trying to generate accounts concurrently using go channels (below is simplified code), however I see that it's not generating all accounts:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/segmentio/ksuid"
)

const ConcurrencyLevel = 10

const TotalAccounts = 30

type (
    Accounts []Account

     Account struct {
        AccountID   string
    }
)

func GenerateRandomAccountID() (accountReferenceID string){
    return ksuid.New().String()
}

func main() {
    totalAccounts := make(Accounts, 0, TotalAccounts)
    total := 0
    for total < TotalAccounts {
        accounts := make([]Account, ConcurrencyLevel)
        ch := make(chan Account)
        for range accounts {
            go func() {
                accountID := GenerateRandomAccountID()
                account := Account{AccountID: accountID}
                ch <- account
            }()
        }

        for k, _ := range accounts {
            account := <-ch
            accounts[k] = account
        }
        totalAccounts = append(totalAccounts, accounts...)
        total += len(totalAccounts)
        close(ch)
    }
    fmt.Printf("total is : %d\n", total)
    fmt.Printf("total accounts generated is : %d\n", len(totalAccounts))

}
```

It prints out

```
total is : 30
total accounts generated is : 20
```

expecting total accounts generated to be 30 in this case.

https://go.dev/play/p/UtFhE2nidaP

Comment: Typo?  Use `total += len(accounts)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your logic:

```golang
totalAccounts = append(totalAccounts, accounts...)
total += len(totalAccounts)
```

Say this is the second iteration through the loop. `totalAccounts` already contains 10 items, you add another 10 so the length is now 20. You then take `total` (which will be 10 from the first run through) and add `len(totalAccounts)` (20) to give a result of 30. This means that your loop (`for total < TotalAccounts`) completes earlier than it should.

To fix this you could use [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/9HrGITrlf5j):

```golang
totalAccounts = append(totalAccounts, accounts...)
total += len(accounts) // Add the number of NEW accounts
```

or

```golang
totalAccounts = append(totalAccounts, accounts...)
total = len(totalAccounts ) // = not +=
```